# How to use data-attr to create an anchor in selectbox

Tags: javascript, select, onchange

When choosing an option from a selectbox, i want to create an anchor.
Below works fine:

```
<select class="form-select name" onchange="location = this.value;">
    <option value="Naam" selected>Naam</option>             
    <option class="" value="index.php?name=John">John</option>
    <option class="" value="index.php?name=Susan">Susan</option>
</select>
```

But i prefer to seperate the anchor from the value.
So i thought something like this should also work but unfortunately:

```
<select class="form-select name" onchange="location = this.attr.data-anchor;">
    <option value="Naam" selected>Naam</option>             
    <option class="" data-anchor="index.php?name=John" value="John">John</option>
    <option class="" data-anchor="index.php?name=Susan" value="Susan">Susan</option>    

</select>
```

Is there a way i can use something like `data-anchor` and trigger on that value with select?

Comment: Have you tried location=this.dataset.anchor; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<select class="form-select name" onchange="location = (this.selectedOptions[0].dataset.anchor);">
    <option value="Naam" selected>Naam</option>             
    <option class="" data-anchor="index.php?name=John" value="John">John</option>
    <option class="" data-anchor="index.php?name=Susan" value="Susan">Susan</option>    

</select>
```